# Rank of a linear operator given its characteristic and minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T\colon V \to V$ be a linear operator on the vector space $V$ with characteristic polynomial $\lambda^4(\lambda-4)^5$ and minimal polynomial $\lambda(\lambda-4)$, then what is the rank of $T$?

Comment: So, what is your  _'problem'_?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes but not worked.

Comment: Use Jordon form

Comment: Can you do it black horse?

Comment: @sharafatsalam At least share what you have tried – how are others supposed to help you otherwise? If you don't show any effort, others will be less likely to answer your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The Jordon form of that matrix will be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
(0)_4&0\\
0&(4)_5\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $(0)_4$ is $4\times 4$ zero matrix and $(4)_5$ is $5\times 5$ diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $4$. Hence the rank is $5$

Answer (score 1):

The minimal polynomial is of the form $(x-a)(x-b)$ hence the matrix is diagonalizable and hence rank is 5